# is it possible to load scala classes "dynamic"? (like pythons import_module)

Tags: scala

at the moment I'm try to write an API with Scala. This API should handle file backends, like Smb, S3, FileSystem Storage, etc.

So I wrote some classes like `Storage` which is a base class for storage backends and the Subclasses like `FileSystemStorage`, `SmbStorage` which subclasses `Storage` but from now on, i want to use those classes if i specify them in a settings file.

I wanted it like it is in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE Where i could specifiy a string, to my default storage engine.

And then it should "magically" work so that I could use DefaultStorage to access either `FileSystemStorage` or `SmbStorage` also it should be possible to create more "storage" classes. is this even possible?

Currently I have something in my mind how i could realize this, but I'm unsure if this is good practice in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM classes are already loaded dynamically. What you want is to choose an instance dynamically.

You can do something like:

```
def byName(name:String) = name match {
  "FileSystemStorage" => FileSystemStorage
  "SmbStorage" => SmbStorage
}
```

I am assuming these are objects. If they are classes, just add a `new` keyword.

Now, if the class name is unknown at compile time you can do `Class.forName(full_qualified_classname)`. But this will give you a `Class` object, not the instance for the class, in which case you will need to invoke `newInstance` (assuming it has an argument-less constructor). The way you described your problem suggests you don't want this approach.